# Views slideshow without jQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, theming, views

I have a view slideshow that I managed to set up by following [these instructions](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7).

I want to use a responsive slider plugin instead of the jQuery Cycle plugin in *Views Style Settings*. How can I use this [JavaScript code](http://responsiveslides.com/) to create the slideshow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why my question was downvoted but here is the answer.

I created a views block for my custom content type "Slider Images" and called it "Home Page Slider". I set the "Slider Images" Link and Image as Fields in the view and formatted it as an HTML list.

In my template.php file I used this function

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
   $view = $vars['view'];
   // if Home Page Slider View add the appropriate js and css
   if($view->name == 'home_page_slider') {
     // add needed javascript
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/js/responsiveslides.min.js');
     // add needed stylesheet
     drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') .'/css/responsiveslides.css');
   }
}
```

to add my JS and CSS needed for the responsive slider plugin I wanted to use

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, however:

I have tried a bunch of slideshows that claim various degrees of responsiveness and the best out of the box solution I have found that works as expected, is easy to set up, and is properly responsive, is the [flexslider](http://drupal.org/project/flexslider) module, which can either be used by itself, or can be used with the [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module.

If you haven't tried it it is definitely worth trying.